# Understanding batching in pytorch models

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

I have following model which forms one of the step in my overall model pipeline:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class NPB(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d, nhead, num_layers, dropout=0.1):
        super(NPB, self).__init__()
            
        self.te = nn.TransformerEncoder(
            nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=d, nhead=nhead, dropout=dropout, batch_first=True),
            num_layers=num_layers,
        ) 

        self.t_emb = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, d))
        
        self.L = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, d)) 

        self.td = nn.TransformerDecoder(
            nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=d, nhead=nhead, dropout=dropout, batch_first=True),
            num_layers=num_layers,
        ) 

        self.ffn = nn.Linear(d, 6)
    
    def forward(self, t_v, t_i):
        print("--------------- t_v, t_i -----------------")
        print('t_v: ', tuple(t_v.shape))
        print('t_i: ', tuple(t_i.shape))

        print("--------------- t_v + t_i + t_emb -----------------")
        _x = t_v + t_i + self.t_emb
        print(tuple(_x.shape))

        print("--------------- te ---------------")
        _x = self.te(_x)
        print(tuple(_x.shape))
        
        print("--------------- td ---------------")
        _x = self.td(self.L, _x)
        print(tuple(_x.shape))

        print("--------------- ffn ---------------")
        _x = self.ffn(_x)
        print(tuple(_x.shape))

        return _x
```

Here `t_v` and `t_i` are inputs from earlier encoder blocks. I pass them as shape of `(4,256)`, where `256` is number of features and `4` is batch size. `t_emb` is temporal embedding.  `L` represents learned matrix representing the embedding of the query. I tested this module block with following code:

```
t_v = torch.randn((4,256))
t_i = torch.randn((4,256))
npb = NPB(d=256, nhead=8, num_layers=2)
npb(t_v, t_i)
```

It outputted:

```
=============== NPB ===============
--------------- t_v, t_i -----------------
t_v:  (4, 256)
t_i:  (4, 256)
--------------- t_v + t_i + t_emb -----------------
(4, 256)
--------------- te ---------------
(4, 256)
--------------- td ---------------
(1, 256)
--------------- ffn ---------------
(1, 6)
```

I was expecting the output should be of shape `(4,6)`, 6 values for each sample in the batch of size `6`. But the output was of size `(1,6)`. After a lot of tweaking, I tried changing `t_emb` and `L` shape from `(1,d)` to `(4,d)`, since I did not wanted all sampled to share these variables (through broadcasting:

```
self.t_emb = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4, d)) # [n, d] = [4, 256]     
self.L = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4, d))
```

This gives desired output of shape (4,6:

```
--------------- t_v, t_i -----------------
t_v:  (4, 256)
t_i:  (4, 256)
--------------- t_v + t_i + t_emb -----------------
(4, 256)
--------------- te ---------------
(4, 256)
--------------- td ---------------
(4, 256)
--------------- ffn ---------------
(4, 6)
```

I have following doubts:

**Q1.** Exactly why changing `L` and `t_emb` shape from `(1,d)` to `(4,d)` worked? Why it did not work with `(1,d)` through broadcasting?
**Q2.** Am I doing batching right way or the output is artificially correct while under the hood its doing something different than what I am expecting (predicting 6 values for each sample in the batch of size 4)?

Comment: Why is 4 the `batch_size`? Wouldn't we expect to pass a sequence `(timesteps, features)` for unbatched or `(batch_size, timestes, features)`?  the [decoder](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerDecoder.html#torch.nn.TransformerDecoder) expects the target sequence as first argument and the output of the encoder as the second argument (for shapes see [transformer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html#torch.nn.Transformer) doc). So that is why `L` is determining the shape in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the docs - [transformer class](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html#torch.nn.Transformer), [transformer decoder](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerDecoderLayer.html#torch.nn.TransformerDecoderLayer)

For an unbatched (2 dim) input where `src = (S, E)` and `tgt = (T, E)`, the output will be of shape `(T, E)`.

In the transformer decoder layer, the first argument is `tgt` which defines the output size.

Since you define your `tgt` param `L` as `torch.randn(1, d)`, your transformer decoder output will be of size `(1, d)`.

This has nothing to do with broadcasting, this is just the input/output mechanics of the transformer layer.